# How do I grep this pattern with regular-expression in shell?

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep the pattern like "1-10","10-20","1-9"(without double quotes) with the following code:

```
grep '[[:digit:]]\-[[:digit:]]' mydoc
```

It is ok to grep "1-9" but I can't figure out how to grep other two patterns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus needs no masking. + allows multiple occurrences.

```
egrep '[0-9]+-[0-9]+' mydoc
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep -E '[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+' mydoc`

`grep -E '[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}' mydoc`

?

Comment: afaik, the '-' needs no masking.